# why does my function returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a filter to stop duplication in submitting forms, I have used findone and checked if it's null returns true and vise versa, but it always returns undefined

```
function checkParticipant(fname, mname, lname, foname){
  Participant.findOne({
    fname: fname,
    mname: mname,
    lname: lname,
    foname: foname
  }, function(err,participant){
    if(participant == null){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Format your code for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
function checkParticipant(fname, mname, lname, foname){
  Partiipant.findOne({fname:fname, mname:mname, lname:lname, foname:foname }).then( participant => (
   if(participant) return false
   else return true;
))
}
```

FindOne returns a promise so you`d have to subscribe to it to get the data.

Comment: As for the if(participant), basically, if the findOne returns a participant, its found and it will return false, vice versa if participant was not found, youll get false

Comment: `return !!participant`  ?

Comment: @thebjorn what?

Comment: Sorry, my eyes crossed a bit.. It should of course be `return !participant;` -- it is a shorter way to write your if/return statement. ( the `return !!participant;` is for when the true branch should return `true`.)

Comment: Oh, something new, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkParticipant` function does not contain a return statement. 
Hence it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A function returns `undefined` if a value was not returned.

Please check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to return from an asynchronous function. This is not possible. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/7868639) answer on how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with code you have returned. Its just about concept of Javascript callback function.

```
function timeOut()
{ 
  setTimeout(function(){ return true; })
};

timeOut(); // returns undefined
```

Executing this function returns undefined becuase, the query has callback function which runs in different context and returns nothing that means undefined.

So to solve your problem, you need to update the code as follows if your ORM supports the promises.

```
function checkParticipant(fname, mname, lname, foname){
   return Partiipant.findOne({fname:fname, mname:mname, lname:lname, foname:foname 
}).then( participant => (
   if(participant == null)
   {
       return true;
   }
   else return false;
  ))
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.